# Как сделать одну сторону Border в разных цветах?

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка

Как можно реализовать Border в разных цветах на одной стороне?
может кто то сталкивался
Пример на изображении
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: через градиент свойство border-image или background-image(тоже градиент),примеры по первой ссылке google border linear gradient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ну как вариант, можно использовать before и after

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 30px;
}
.wrapper:before,
.wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: 7px solid;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.wrapper:before {
  left: 0;
  width: 20%;
  border-right: none;
  border-color: #1f9fda;
}
.wrapper:after {
  right: 0;
  width: 65%; /* calc(80% - 60px) */
  border-left: none;
  border-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus, deleniti? Quidem quibusdam aperiam dolores provident! Voluptas quam nam debitis mollitia.</div>
</div>
```